# Value set to undefined when setting variable from result of fetch from within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

Here is the code snippet:

```
 export default function GetWeather(props) {
 const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  
 const apiKey = "xxxxx";
 const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid=${apiKey}`

 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useeffect")
    const data = fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>  data)

      setWeather({data : data})
      console.log(weather.data)

  }, [apiUrl]);

}
```

The console.log statement prints 'undefined' in the console on browser when I check.

I've checked the network tab and there is data in the response section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useeffect")
    const data = fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>  {
        // here you do what you want with data
        setWeather(data)
        // ... other things to do
      })

  }, [apiUrl]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried the above snippet, and tried to console log weather after setting it, still the value of weather is empty in console and also getting this msg in terminal ->  "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'weather'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Comment: I have passed the variable weather as prop and tested. Its printing the data in console, though inside useEffect I am getting undefined. Now I am unable to access some values from the array in the child component.

Comment: `setState` is async operation, you cant log it immediately after. try `console.log(data)` immediately afetr setState to see what data is available